# Filter PowerPivot table using a cell reference

Tags: vba, excel, filter, powerpivot

So I've tried in vain to get the instructions from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19126266/how-to-update-powerpivot-pivot-table-filter-via-cell-reference) to work with my data.  I keep getting a run-time error 1004.  My goal is to input a company name into cell I1 of the same sheet as the pivot table and then have the pivot table filter by that entry.  Here's my adapted code:

```
Sub filtercompany()
    ' Filtercompany
    Dim FilterValue As String
    FilterValue = ActiveSheet.Range("I1").Value 'get value for filter

    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1") _
        .PivotFields("[Company].[Name].[Name]").ClearAllFilters
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("[Company].[Name].[Name]") _
        .CurrentPageName = "[Company].[Name].&[" & FilterValue & "]"
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried hardcoding the string you pass on the `CurrentPageName` to just see if it works?

Comment: So, no.  The following isn't working for company named AAA.          Sub filtercompany()
    ' Filtercompany
        ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1") _
        .PivotFields("[Company].[Name].[Name]").ClearAllFilters
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("[Company].[Name].[Name]") _
        .CurrentPageName = "[Company].[Name].&[AAA]"
End Sub                                                             Is there an actual way to do this using any type of VBA?  I've tried recording a macro, but that isn't working either.  Is it me or powerpivot?  Or both?

Comment: Do you actually have that PivotField name? I mean, that string is not a standard format. You should be using the actual PivotField name you got in your PowerPivot.

Comment: Yes, those are the names of the fields and table in the PowerPivot data model.  I can make this work in a regular pivot table, but PowerPivot is giving me heartburn...

Answer (score 0):

Check out my string. It Works fine when I gave a projektnumber to i

```
Dim i As Variant

i = 216722

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PiLEverantör").PivotFields( _
    "[Tabell2].[Kolumn1].[Kolumn1]").VisibleItemsList = Array( _
    "[Tabell2].[Kolumn1].&[" & i & "]")
End Sub
```

Comment: I was able to make this work for PowerPivot using the method described by Pierre above, but only once I checked "Select Multiple Items" within the pivot table.